# Xamarin.forms creating popups

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am building a xamarin.forms app. How would I create popups that resemble to UIPopoverPresentationController ?

I need to create popup with a list view and a search text box.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this plugin

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Use it myself for exact same task.

Comment: Thanks @dany dakur. Is there a way I can change the size of popups when using Rg.Plugins.Popup? Currently, it is taking almost entire screen space on ipad screen.

Comment: @user1136391 when creating StackLayout for Content you can specify Padding of the popup: StackLayout main = new StackLayout()
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(80, 80, 80, 80),
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,

            };